# from XEN to VMWare

Tags: debian, vmware, grub, ext4, xfs

I have migrated many xm virtual machine to vmware 
Using http://www.zoobey.com/index.php/resources/all-articles-list/268-xen-to-vmware
 , migrations were very smooth. But now I am struck in a xm machine which has XFS file system, and fdisk -l shows following.
        root@drift:~# fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda1: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 261 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sda1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

This is strange that it has data and does not has partition table. 
I can mount /dev/sda and strange thing is it does not has a partition table.
I can not install bootloader of XFS when I migrate it on vmware. Then I thought/read some where that we can't have a boot loader on XFS filesystem. I then created a ext4 machine and tried to copy all the data using cp -dpRx command from xfs to ext4 file system (running with live CD and mounting both filesystems) this coping has some I/O error which after sometime make the XFS filesystem unreadable. Please tell me how can I have grub on XFS ?
and is there any way to create partition without loosing data